# c# DataGridView EditMode and DeleteKey

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

c# winforms

My DataGridView has:

SelectionMode - CellSelect

EditMode - EditOnKeyStroke

It works well for all Keys except fot DeleteKey (when pressed - nothing happend).

I want - if DeleteKey is pressed - selected Cell (or Cells) stay selected, but - empty value (like in Excel).

Must I create a separate KeyDownEvent for DeleteKey only ?

Comment: This worked for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27007730/how-to-use-default-functionality-for-delete-key-while-in-edit-mode-for-datagridv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The delete key has special significance in (potentially) allowing the user to delete a row from the grid. The Delete key is not permitted to initiate 'Edit' mode in the DataGridView. So, you need to get the cell into Edit mode somehow in order to allow the delete key to be handled by the DataGridViewCell (instead of the DataGridView itself).

To do this, you could either implement a KeyPress handler as you suggest, so that pressing delete gets you into edit mode, before being handled again to delete the content. Or, if that's too much effort you can also change the DataGridView.EditMode to 'OnEnter', in which case each cell is always put into edit mode upon gaining focus, either by mouse or tabbing between cells. Then, pressing delete will cause the contents to be deleted.

Comment: Clear. But something is wrong in MSLogic. The DelKey can have "special significance" to delete row if dgv has SelectionMode = FullRowSelect. But if dgv is in CellSellectMode - the "special significance" should be - delete cellContent (or maybe deleteCell), and not - "deleteNothing". AnyWay, Thanks for your explanation.

Comment: That's one interpretation for sure, but API design is always subjective. :-)