# How to use default functionality for delete key while in edit mode for DataGridView?

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my spreadsheet program, I currently have functionality for when the user presses the delete key on a cell, it sets the cell's value to an empty string; however, when the user presses delete while editing a cell, the default functionality of the delete key does not work. My current implementation for the delete key is as follows:

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (false == dataGridView1.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell selected_cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            Cell change_cell = _workbook.CurrentSpreadsheet.GetCell(selected_cell.RowIndex, selected_cell.ColumnIndex);

            // The text is not null nor empty
            if (false == string.IsNullOrEmpty(change_cell.Text))
            {
                change_cell.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
    // The user is editing a cell 
    else
    {
        // When the user presses delete, use the default functionality
        // as in remove one character each press. 
    }
}
```

For my else statement, is there a way to enable the delete key's default functionality while editing a cell?

Comment: what if user actually want to delete a single character instead of setting empty string to the cell?

Comment: That's the issue I'm trying to solve.

Comment: OK, I misunderstood your question. But `deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click` seems to be the click event handler of a menu item, not the handler for the Delete key. Does the Delete key stroke triggers the menu item's click event handler?

Comment: Yes, pressing delete triggers the menu item click event handler. My original implementation used a dataGridView1_KeyDown event for delete. That solution works for pressing delete while in a cell, so I may just revert back to it.

Comment: actually, I can't reproduce your issue, it is working as expected. see my code, i have to post it as an answer;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it is working as expected.

```
private void deleteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeleteCellsIfNotInEditMode();
}

private void dataGridView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        DeleteCellsIfNotInEditMode();
    }
}

private void DeleteCellsIfNotInEditMode()
{
    if (!dataGridView1.CurrentCell.IsInEditMode)
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewCell selected_cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
        {
            selected_cell.Value = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had been chasing this problem down for so many hours. In this form project I inherited I finally found what had stolen my delete key. The delete key had been assigned to a context menu item I never used. This was preventing the default action (removing a single character) from executing while editing a cell.

For individuals viewing this post in the future, a search solution-wide (though likely in the Designer.cs file for your form) for

```
.ShortcutKeys = System.Windows.Forms.Keys.Delete;
```

will help to find the offending item that has stolen your delete key.